# Connection Refused when creating a two nodes cluster in Apache NiFi

Tags: cluster-computing, load-balancing, apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

I'm facing a problem regarding a refused connection on the cluster node protocol port.

I'm using the following configs to create the two nodes cluster:

For the First node manager :

```
####################
# State Management #
####################
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider
# The ID of the cluster-wide state provider. This will be ignored if NiFi is not clustered but must be populated if running in a cluster.
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=true
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start> is set to true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties

# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=10.129.140.22
nifi.web.http.port=3000
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=10000
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=

# cluster load balancing properties #
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6342
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=4
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec


# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=localhost:2181
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi
```

For the second node slave:

```
####################
# State Management #
####################
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider
# The ID of the cluster-wide state provider. This will be ignored if NiFi is not clustered but must be populated if running in a cluster.
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=false
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start> is set to true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties


# web properties #
nifi.web.war.directory=./lib
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=9021
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=
nifi.web.https.port=
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.node.address=
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=10001
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=

# cluster load balancing properties #
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=10.129.140.22
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6343
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=4
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec

# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=10.129.140.22:2181
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi
```

The logs fils shows the following :
For the slave

```
2019-05-23 10:37:07,384 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Initializing FileSystemRepository with 'Always Sync' set to false
2019-05-23 10:37:07,541 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Not enabling RAW Socket Site-to-Site functionality because nifi.remote.input.socket.port is not set
2019-05-23 10:37:07,546 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Checking if there is already a Cluster Coordinator Elected...
2019-05-23 10:37:07,591 INFO [main] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Starting
2019-05-23 10:37:07,658 INFO [main-EventThread] o.a.c.f.state.ConnectionStateManager State change: CONNECTED
2019-05-23 10:37:07,693 INFO [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
2019-05-23 10:37:07,697 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController The Election for Cluster Coordinator has already begun (Leader is localhost:10000). Will not register to be elected for this role until after connecting to the cluster and inheriting the cluster's flow.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,699 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=true] Registered new Leader Selector for role Cluster Coordinator; this node is a silent observer in the election.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,699 INFO [main] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Starting
2019-05-23 10:37:07,703 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=false] Registered new Leader Selector for role Cluster Coordinator; this node is a silent observer in the election.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,703 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=false] started
2019-05-23 10:37:07,703 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.c.h.AbstractHeartbeatMonitor Heartbeat Monitor started
2019-05-23 10:37:07,706 INFO [main-EventThread] o.a.c.f.state.ConnectionStateManager State change: CONNECTED
2019-05-23 10:37:09,587 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1a6a4595{nifi-api,/nifi-api,file:///home/superman/nifi-1.9.2/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.9.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.9.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-api-1.9.2.war}
2019-05-23 10:37:09,850 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=77ms
2019-05-23 10:37:09,852 INFO [main] o.e.j.s.h.C._nifi_content_viewer No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2019-05-23 10:37:09,873 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4b1b2255{nifi-content-viewer,/nifi-content-viewer,file:///home/superman/nifi-1.9.2/work/jetty/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.9.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.9.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.9.2.war}
2019-05-23 10:37:09,895 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=6ms
2019-05-23 10:37:09,896 WARN [main] o.e.j.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor Duplicate mapping from / to default
2019-05-23 10:37:09,915 INFO [main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler._nifi_docs No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2019-05-23 10:37:09,917 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4965454c{nifi-docs,/nifi-docs,file:///home/superman/nifi-1.9.2/work/jetty/nifi-web-docs-1.9.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.9.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-docs-1.9.2.war}
2019-05-23 10:37:09,936 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=8ms
2019-05-23 10:37:09,955 INFO [main] o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler._ No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2019-05-23 10:37:09,957 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1e4a4ed5{nifi-error,/,file:///home/superman/nifi-1.9.2/work/jetty/nifi-web-error-1.9.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.9.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-error-1.9.2.war}
2019-05-23 10:37:09,967 INFO [main] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Started ServerConnector@4518bffd{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9021}
2019-05-23 10:37:09,967 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @28769ms
2019-05-23 10:37:09,978 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading Flow...
2019-05-23 10:37:09,982 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.io.socket.SocketListener Now listening for connections from nodes on port 10001
2019-05-23 10:37:10,026 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Successfully synchronized controller with proposed flow
2019-05-23 10:37:10,071 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Connecting Node: localhost:9021
2019-05-23 10:37:10,073 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.c.n.LeaderElectionNodeProtocolSender Determined that Cluster Coordinator is located at localhost:10000; will use this address for sending heartbeat messages
2019-05-23 10:37:10,074 WARN [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Failed to connect to cluster due to: org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: Failed to create socket to localhost:10000 due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2019-05-23 10:37:12,715 WARN [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Failed to determine which node is elected active Cluster Coordinator: ZooKeeper reports the address as localhost:10000, but there is no node with this address. Attempted to determine the node's information but failed to retrieve its information due to org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: Failed to create socket due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2019-05-23 10:37:12,720 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Event Reported for localhost:9021 -- Received heartbeat from node previously disconnected due to Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster. Issuing reconnection request.
2019-05-23 10:37:12,721 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Event Reported for localhost:9021 -- Requesting that node connect to cluster
2019-05-23 10:37:12,721 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Status of localhost:9021 changed from NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=localhost:9021, state=DISCONNECTED, Disconnect Code=Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster, Disconnect Reason=Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster, updateId=1] to NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=localhost:9021, state=CONNECTING, updateId=3]
2019-05-23 10:37:15,075 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.c.n.LeaderElectionNodeProtocolSender Determined that Cluster Coordinator is located at localhost:10000; will use this address for sending heartbeat messages
2019-05-23 10:37:15,076 WARN [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Failed to connect to cluster due to: org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: Failed to create socket to localhost:10000 due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

For the manager

```
2019-05-23 10:36:59,752 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2019-05-23 10:36:59,752 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2019-05-23 10:36:59,752 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2019-05-23 10:36:59,752 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Server environment:os.name=Linux
2019-05-23 10:36:59,752 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2019-05-23 10:36:59,753 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Server environment:os.version=4.15.0-20-generic
2019-05-23 10:36:59,753 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Server environment:user.name=root
2019-05-23 10:36:59,753 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Server environment:user.home=/root
2019-05-23 10:36:59,753 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Server environment:user.dir=/home/superman/nifi-1.9.2
2019-05-23 10:36:59,753 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer tickTime set to 2000
2019-05-23 10:36:59,754 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer minSessionTimeout set to -1
2019-05-23 10:36:59,754 INFO [main] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer maxSessionTimeout set to -1
2019-05-23 10:36:59,855 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Checking if there is already a Cluster Coordinator Elected...
2019-05-23 10:36:59,903 INFO [main] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Starting
2019-05-23 10:36:59,950 INFO [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:40388
2019-05-23 10:36:59,950 INFO [SyncThread:0] o.a.z.server.persistence.FileTxnLog Creating new log file: log.3c
2019-05-23 10:36:59,963 INFO [SyncThread:0] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Established session 0x16ae443f4130000 with negotiated timeout 4000 for client /127.0.0.1:40388
2019-05-23 10:36:59,975 INFO [main-EventThread] o.a.c.f.state.ConnectionStateManager State change: CONNECTED
2019-05-23 10:36:59,998 INFO [Curator-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
2019-05-23 10:37:00,003 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController The Election for Cluster Coordinator has already begun (Leader is localhost:10001). Will not register to be elected for this role until after connecting to the cluster and inheriting the cluster's flow.
2019-05-23 10:37:00,005 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=true] Registered new Leader Selector for role Cluster Coordinator; this node is a silent observer in the election.
2019-05-23 10:37:00,005 INFO [main] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl Starting
2019-05-23 10:37:00,017 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=false] Registered new Leader Selector for role Cluster Coordinator; this node is a silent observer in the election.
2019-05-23 10:37:00,017 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=false] started
2019-05-23 10:37:00,017 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.c.h.AbstractHeartbeatMonitor Heartbeat Monitor started
2019-05-23 10:37:00,019 INFO [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:40390
2019-05-23 10:37:00,020 INFO [SyncThread:0] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Established session 0x16ae443f4130001 with negotiated timeout 4000 for client /127.0.0.1:40390
2019-05-23 10:37:00,020 INFO [main-EventThread] o.a.c.f.state.ConnectionStateManager State change: CONNECTED
2019-05-23 10:37:02,022 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1a05ff8e{nifi-api,/nifi-api,file:///home/superman/nifi-1.9.2/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.9.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.9.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-api-1.9.2.war}
2019-05-23 10:37:02,373 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=165ms
2019-05-23 10:37:02,375 INFO [main] o.e.j.s.h.C._nifi_content_viewer No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2019-05-23 10:37:02,401 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@251e2f4a{nifi-content-viewer,/nifi-content-viewer,file:///home/superman/nifi-1.9.2/work/jetty/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.9.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.9.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.9.2.war}
2019-05-23 10:37:02,419 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=6ms
2019-05-23 10:37:02,420 WARN [main] o.e.j.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor Duplicate mapping from / to default
2019-05-23 10:37:02,421 INFO [main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler._nifi_docs No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2019-05-23 10:37:02,441 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1abea1ed{nifi-docs,/nifi-docs,file:///home/superman/nifi-1.9.2/work/jetty/nifi-web-docs-1.9.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.9.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-docs-1.9.2.war}
2019-05-23 10:37:02,457 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=6ms
2019-05-23 10:37:02,475 INFO [main] o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler._ No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2019-05-23 10:37:02,478 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6f5288c5{nifi-error,/,file:///home/superman/nifi-1.9.2/work/jetty/nifi-web-error-1.9.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.9.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-error-1.9.2.war}
2019-05-23 10:37:02,488 INFO [main] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Started ServerConnector@167ed1cf{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{10.129.140.22:3000}
2019-05-23 10:37:02,488 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @26145ms
2019-05-23 10:37:02,500 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Loading Flow...
2019-05-23 10:37:02,503 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.io.socket.SocketListener Now listening for connections from nodes on port 10000
2019-05-23 10:37:02,545 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Successfully synchronized controller with proposed flow
2019-05-23 10:37:02,587 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Connecting Node: 10.129.140.22:3000
2019-05-23 10:37:02,589 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.c.n.LeaderElectionNodeProtocolSender Determined that Cluster Coordinator is located at localhost:10001; will use this address for sending heartbeat messages
2019-05-23 10:37:02,590 WARN [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Failed to connect to cluster due to: org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: Failed to create socket to localhost:10001 due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2019-05-23 10:37:04,001 INFO [SessionTracker] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Expiring session 0x16ae42f180d0003, timeout of 4000ms exceeded
2019-05-23 10:37:04,001 INFO [SessionTracker] o.a.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer Expiring session 0x16ae42f180d0002, timeout of 4000ms exceeded
2019-05-23 10:37:05,026 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Event Reported for 10.129.140.22:3000 -- Received heartbeat from node previously disconnected due to Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster. Issuing reconnection request.
2019-05-23 10:37:05,028 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Event Reported for 10.129.140.22:3000 -- Requesting that node connect to cluster
2019-05-23 10:37:05,028 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Status of 10.129.140.22:3000 changed from NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=DISCONNECTED, Disconnect Code=Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster, Disconnect Reason=Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster, updateId=0] to NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=5]
2019-05-23 10:37:07,591 WARN [main] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService There is currently no Cluster Coordinator. This often happens upon restart of NiFi when running an embedded ZooKeeper. Will register this node to become the active Cluster Coordinator and will attempt to connect to cluster again
2019-05-23 10:37:07,594 INFO [main] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager CuratorLeaderElectionManager[stopped=false] Registered new Leader Selector for role Cluster Coordinator; this node is an active participant in the election.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,612 INFO [Leader Election Notification Thread-1] o.a.n.c.l.e.CuratorLeaderElectionManager org.apache.nifi.controller.leader.election.CuratorLeaderElectionManager$ElectionListener@1d6dcdcb This node has been elected Leader for Role 'Cluster Coordinator'
2019-05-23 10:37:07,612 INFO [Leader Election Notification Thread-1] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController This node elected Active Cluster Coordinator
2019-05-23 10:37:07,668 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Event Reported for 10.129.140.22:3000 -- Received heartbeat from node previously disconnected due to Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster. Issuing reconnection request.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,668 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Event Reported for 10.129.140.22:3000 -- Requesting that node connect to cluster
2019-05-23 10:37:07,669 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Status of 10.129.140.22:3000 changed from NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=DISCONNECTED, Disconnect Code=Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster, Disconnect Reason=Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster, updateId=1] to NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=6]
2019-05-23 10:37:07,675 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Event Reported for 10.129.140.22:3000 -- Received heartbeat from node previously disconnected due to Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster. Issuing reconnection request.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,675 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Event Reported for 10.129.140.22:3000 -- Requesting that node connect to cluster
2019-05-23 10:37:07,675 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Status of 10.129.140.22:3000 changed from NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=DISCONNECTED, Disconnect Code=Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster, Disconnect Reason=Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster, updateId=2] to NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=7]
2019-05-23 10:37:07,694 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Status of 10.129.140.22:3000 changed from NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=5] to NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=5]
2019-05-23 10:37:07,695 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Event Reported for 10.129.140.22:3000 -- Received heartbeat from node previously disconnected due to Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster. Issuing reconnection request.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,699 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Event Reported for 10.129.140.22:3000 -- Requesting that node connect to cluster
2019-05-23 10:37:07,700 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Status of 10.129.140.22:3000 changed from NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=DISCONNECTED, Disconnect Code=Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster, Disconnect Reason=Has Not Yet Connected to Cluster, updateId=3] to NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=8]
2019-05-23 10:37:07,701 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-5] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Status of 10.129.140.22:3000 changed from NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=7] to NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=7]
2019-05-23 10:37:07,702 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-1] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Finished processing request 19834836-9bda-41b3-8fef-4a288d90c7bf (type=NODE_STATUS_CHANGE, length=1103 bytes) from localhost.localdomain in 33 millis
2019-05-23 10:37:07,702 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-5] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Finished processing request 85b0bb3f-c2a6-4dfd-abd6-e9df14710c4d (type=NODE_STATUS_CHANGE, length=1103 bytes) from localhost.localdomain in 10 millis
2019-05-23 10:37:07,703 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-3] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Status of 10.129.140.22:3000 changed from NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=6] to NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=6]
2019-05-23 10:37:07,705 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-3] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Finished processing request 80447901-4ad3-44e3-91ad-d9f075624eae (type=NODE_STATUS_CHANGE, length=1103 bytes) from localhost.localdomain in 31 millis
2019-05-23 10:37:07,706 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Processing reconnection request from cluster coordinator.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,706 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Received a Reconnection Request that contained no DataFlow. Will attempt to connect to cluster using local flow.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,707 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-2] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Finished processing request 22cdceee-c01f-445f-a091-38812e878d10 (type=RECONNECTION_REQUEST, length=3095 bytes) from 10.129.140.22:3000 in 34 millis
2019-05-23 10:37:07,708 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Processing reconnection request from cluster coordinator.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,708 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Received a Reconnection Request that contained no DataFlow. Will attempt to connect to cluster using local flow.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,709 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-4] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Finished processing request 8605cf39-2034-4ee2-92c4-0fbe54e97fb2 (type=RECONNECTION_REQUEST, length=3013 bytes) from 10.129.140.22:3000 in 27 millis
2019-05-23 10:37:07,712 INFO [Reconnect 10.129.140.22:3000] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Successfully requested that 10.129.140.22:3000 join the cluster
2019-05-23 10:37:07,712 INFO [Reconnect 10.129.140.22:3000] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Successfully requested that 10.129.140.22:3000 join the cluster
2019-05-23 10:37:07,725 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-6] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Finished processing request 0ca55348-44eb-416b-91dd-3d80da4c5ebe (type=RECONNECTION_REQUEST, length=3013 bytes) from 10.129.140.22:3000 in 29 millis
2019-05-23 10:37:07,725 INFO [Reconnect 10.129.140.22:3000] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Successfully requested that 10.129.140.22:3000 join the cluster
2019-05-23 10:37:07,728 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-7] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Status of 10.129.140.22:3000 changed from NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=8] to NodeConnectionStatus[nodeId=10.129.140.22:3000, state=CONNECTING, updateId=8]
2019-05-23 10:37:07,728 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-7] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Finished processing request c9b647d7-67ac-4d0a-833b-8a0a8cc0ba6d (type=NODE_STATUS_CHANGE, length=1103 bytes) from localhost.localdomain in 3 millis
2019-05-23 10:37:07,728 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Connecting Node: 10.129.140.22:3000
2019-05-23 10:37:07,725 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Processing reconnection request from cluster coordinator.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,732 INFO [Heartbeat Monitor Thread-1] o.a.n.c.c.h.AbstractHeartbeatMonitor Finished processing 4 heartbeats in 2 seconds, 708 millis
2019-05-23 10:37:07,732 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Received a Reconnection Request that contained no DataFlow. Will attempt to connect to cluster using local flow.
2019-05-23 10:37:07,733 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.n.c.c.n.LeaderElectionNodeProtocolSender Determined that Cluster Coordinator is located at localhost:10000; will use this address for sending heartbeat messages
2019-05-23 10:37:07,734 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Connecting Node: 10.129.140.22:3000
2019-05-23 10:37:07,735 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Connecting Node: 10.129.140.22:3000
2019-05-23 10:37:07,736 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.n.c.c.n.LeaderElectionNodeProtocolSender Determined that Cluster Coordinator is located at localhost:10000; will use this address for sending heartbeat messages
2019-05-23 10:37:07,736 INFO [Reconnect to Cluster] o.a.n.c.c.n.LeaderElectionNodeProtocolSender Determined that Cluster Coordinator is located at localhost:10000; will use this address for sending heartbeat messages
2019-05-23 10:37:07,748 INFO [Process Cluster Protocol Request-8] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Finished processing request 434daf63-1beb-4b82-9290-bb0da4e89b7f (type=RECONNECTION_REQUEST, length=2972 bytes) from 10.129.140.22:3000 in 16 millis
2019-05-23 10:37:07,749 INFO [Reconnect 10.129.140.22:3000] o.a.n.c.c.node.NodeClusterCoordinator Successfully requested that 10.129.140.22:3000 join the cluster**
```

Answer (score 1):

Set these properties on both:

```
  nifi.web.http.host=<host> 
  nifi.cluster.node.address=<host>
```

Beware of this value visibility in network scopes:

```
  nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=localhost:2181
```

**e.g 'localhost'**, in the other side you're using real IP addr

They share it during replication, primary/coordinator node election and flow election.